# How do I pass an image location to a child component in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-cli

I can't get my image to show up for some reason. The path of the image should be sent to the component and rendered there. But it just doesn't render. I believe I am using the Vue-CLI if that helps.

This is my folder structure:

```
src
 | App.vue
 | bulbasaur.png
 | /components
       | Pokemon.vue
```

**App.vue**

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Pokemon location="./bulbasaur.png"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Pokemon from './components/Pokemon.vue'

  export default {
    name: "app",
    components: {
      Pokemon
    }
  };
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

**Pokemon.vue**

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <img :src="`${location}`" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Pokemon',
    props: {
      location: String
    }
  };
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error in console or network tab due to image path is not correct, etc?

Comment: No, there is no error. The element is created as: `<img data-v-3848655a="" src="./bulbasaur.png">` but only a broken image link is displayed.

Comment: Can you try once to put the images into `public` folder instead like this: [html-and-static-assets](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder)

Comment: I moved it into `/public` and tried referencing it with `location="../../public/bulbasaur.png"` and `location="../public/bulbasaur.png"` but it didn't work.

Comment: Please read the docs fully. In templates, you will need to first pass the base URL to your component. Then you can use it like: <img :src="`${publicPath}my-image.png`">

Comment: Ah, thank you! I finally got it working! I had to add `data () {return {publicPath: process.env.BASE_URL}` in my `export default` and then it worked! Thanks!

Comment: Hi! You can also use require to avoid importing the path in each component `<img :src="require('@/plubic/bulbasaur.png')">, give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

First, create an image prop in your child component:

```
props: {
    image: {
        type: String,
        default: ""
    }
}
...
```

Add the img tag in the child component:

```
<img :src="image" />
```

Import the image in the parent component:

```
import MyImage from '../path/to/my/image';
```

For Vue3, make sure to provide the loaded image to the template:

```
setup() {
    return {
        MyImage
    };
}
```

For Vue2, you can add it in your data section:

```
data() {
    return {
        MyImage: MyImage
    };
}
```

Then just pass the image to your child prop:

```
<child :image="MyImage" />
```